# Problemas con caracteres especiales y replace JSP

Tags: java, jsp, caracteres, replace

soy nuevo aqui. acudo a la comunidad por un problema que tengo con caracteres especiles en un jsp, directamente en un recuadro de area, el tema es que al capturar los datos como àèìòùÑ los convierte a caracteres raros como "Ã¡     Ã©    Ã­-     Ã³     Ãº      Ã±]"
este tema ya se me ha presentado antes y lo solucione con el metodo Replace pero ahora es distinto, uso el metodo replace pero no esta capturando el caracter para transformarlo. si pruebo con otra letra normal si lo hace y si lo convierte, sin embargo con el caracter especial no, les dejo el codigo empleado;

```java
function validarCaracteres() {  
        var mensaje = "";
        mensaje = $("mensaje").value;   
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ã¡/g,"á");
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ã©/g,"é");
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ã­-/g,"í");
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ã³/g,"ó");
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ãº/g,"ú");
        mensaje = mensaje.replace(/\Ã±/g,"ñ");
     
        $('mensaje').value = mensaje;
        return true;
```

espero su respuesta. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, la razón por la cuál recibes esos caracteres es por la codificación del JSP. Para cambiar la codificación basta con establecerla con [`setCharacterEncoding`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-). Muy seguramente tu problema se solucione si simplemente añades esta línea antes de procesar la información

```java
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

De igual manera para trabajar tus respuestas del JSP puedes establecer el formato y en dado caso la codificación que lleva con [`setContentType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-):

```java
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Si quisieras usar varios Headers o repertirlos en varias de tus peticiones, igual podrías hacer uso de la clase [HttpHeaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpHeaders.html).

---

Además, si sólo quisieras recibir acentos agudos, para evitar otros problemas podemos normalizar el texto de entrada a NFD con [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html) la cual nos separa los acentos (sea: diéresis, acento grave, acento agudo, acento circunflejo , etc) en letra y acento.

`"schön" ----NFD----> "scho\u0308n"`

Para la solución

1. Normalizamos el texto con [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html)
2. Reemplazamos los acentos con ([`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)))
3. Volvemos a juntar los caracteres

```java
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Mè gûstán lös acËntos";
        frase = Normalizer.normalize(
                Normalizer.normalize(
                        frase,
                        Normalizer.Form.NFD
                ).replaceAll(
                        "[\\u0300-\\u036f]",
                        "\u0301"),
                Normalizer.Form.NFC
        );

        System.out.println(frase);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Mé gústán lós acÉntos
```

Comment: Hola eduardo gracias por tu respuesta, en primera donde es que se debe agregar el request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

Comment: y en segunda; el tema es que el contexto del codigo no permite realiza la normalizacion, si pudieras dejarme un email de contacto seria genial para que puedas asistirme, te agradezco de antemano

Comment: Se coloca en el JSP, ahí para recibir bien los datos. La verdad tuve un poco de duda porque en las etiquetas y el título mencionas Java y los JSP. `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` se coloca en el servlet para indicarle que tiene una codificación x, puse UTF-8 como ejemplo pues es la que creo que te serviría, pero hay más.

Comment: Si lo que te falla es la codificación de la respuesta... Primero asegúrate que estés enviando bien los datos, especificándole el charset si es necesario al response; también que tu cliente (tu navegador y HTML) estén en concordancia con el charset